# Using nested class of template parameter in CRTP

Tags: c++

Suppose I define a template `T` that uses a nested class of the template parameter `P`, as follows:

```
template<class P> class T
{
public:
    T(P& p) : p(p) {}
    P& p;
    typename P::Nested& get_nested()    { return p.nested; }
};
```

If I declare a class `A` that includes a nested class named `Nested`, I can define a variable of type `T<A>` with no problem:

```
class A
{
public:
    class Nested
    {
    public:
        int i;
    };
    Nested nested;
};

void test2a()
{
    A a;
    a.nested.i = 1;
    T<A> t_a(a);
    t_a.get_nested().i = 2;
}
```

Now, I want to declare a class `B` that, in the same way, includes a nested class named `Nested` and that inherits from `T<B>`, as follows:

```
class B : public T<B>
{
public:
    class Nested
    {
    public:
        int i;
    };
    Nested nested;
};
```

Compilation of the above code fails with error: "**Nested** is not a member of **B**"

I think I understand what's happening: at the time the template is entered, class B is incompletely defined because of inheritance.

However, I am wondering if there is any way to do such a thing...

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 8):

You need to defer the resolution of the return type of `get_nested` until it is called.

One way to do this is to make the return type dependent on a template parameter:

```
  template<typename unused = void>
    typename std::conditional<false, unused, P>::type::Nested&
    get_nested()    { return p.nested; }
```

Another way (since C++14) is to use return type deduction:

```
  auto& get_nested()    { return p.nested; }
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution and it worked great! I don't really your explanation that "defer the resolution of the return type of get_nested until it is called". Do you mean it's resolved at running time? But I thought all template including get_nested is expanded at running time?

Comment: No, this all happens at compile time - but compile time is split into ["phases"](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/translation_phases). What's going on here is that template instantiations occur later in compilation, after the whole file is read.

Comment: looks like that the linked "Phases of translation" didn't length about template/ dependent name lookup. But I'm guessing that in order to make the example work, nested template are looked up after the whole file is read (and therefore the class definitions are completed)? Was this due to sfinae (Because you put into std::conditional trait)

Comment: Yes, the return type is being looked up after the whole file is read and so the class definitions are complete. No, it's not dependent on SFINAE - although because of SFINAE, if something goes wrong the error will be that `get_nested` cannot be resolved, rather than that `P::Nested` cannot be resolved.

Answer (score 4):

I was able to have your example compile with simply

```
template<class P> class T
{
public:
    T(P& p) : p(p) {}
    P& p;
    auto& get_nested()    { return p.nested; }
};
```

Another approach, exploiting the same trick as @ecatmur, but a bit simpler:

```
template<class R = P>
typename R::Nested& get_nested()    { return p.nested; }
```

Similarly, here the compiler has to postpone evaluation of `P::Nested` until you call `get_nested()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for these tricks, both Petr and ecatmur. However, I am using MSVC 2010 compiler which wont compile any of them. I am seriously thinking about upgrading to C++14 compliant compiler... now. Anyway, thanks a lot for your answers.

Comment: @SharpDressedMan, what's the exact problem and exact error message with my second solution? It seems to be even C++03 for me...

Comment: Error is <b>C4519: default template arguments are only allowed on a class template</b>.

Comment: I can change this error to a warning using "#pragma warning (1 : 4519)" but compilation fails a bit later on line "t_a.get_nested().i = 2;", with error C2783: "could not deduce template argument for 'R'". Error fixed using "t_a.get_nested<A>().i", but not that great. This works, anyway, thanks.

Comment: @SharpDressedMan, try to make `get_nested` a functor then. I will probably add such a solution when I get to a computer (I'm on tablet now)

Comment: @SharpDressedMan, hm, it does not seem to be possible with functor, as anyway we need to have a function with a default argument somewhere.

Comment: & @ecatmur: Yes indeed, a functor does not work. The solutions that work are the template functions proposed by you, Petr, and by ecatmur. However, for both of them, the default parameter does not work at compile time (don't know why) and I must explicitly call `t_a.get_nested<A>().i` (for your solution) or `t_a.get_nested<void>().i` (for ecatmur solution). These are working workarounds but, not that ideal though... Anyway, thanks to both of you.